# Are goroutines on a single core faster?

Tags: go

If the server I run go code on only has a single core, can I expect better performance by running goroutines on it? Is yes, why is it faster when there is no parallelism going on?

Comment: I encourage you to watch this video from go co-creator Rob Pike on this topic: https://blog.golang.org/concurrency-is-not-parallelism

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on the code and what you're blocking on. If you're blocking on I/O (but still have other non-I/O work to do), then multiple goroutines on a single core can be dramatically faster. If you're blocking on the CPU, then multiple goroutines is likely somewhat slower due to extra overhead. If you're blocking on memory, then multiple goroutines could be dramatically slower due to additional contention and cache-invalidation. There is no general answer; it depends on what problem you're solving with concurrency, and how you implement it.

Comment: It is only CPU-limited, so I got my answer.

Comment: If your CPU usage is at 100%, there's nothing concurrency can possibly do to let you use more CPU than that.